# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]",

Tags: python, json

I'm using python flask to learn rest api's. My application returns response in json format. I'm able to run it with @approute endpoints, but my remote server asks for json object. I have read many sources and tried all, but nothing helps. I'm new to python environment i know its silly but I couldn't find exact solutions. Kindly help me solve this. 
Postman ERROR : A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1].

```py
import datetime    
import json    
from flask import Flask    

app = Flask (__ name__)     
date_time = datetime.datetime.now()    

@app.route('/properties/value', methods=['GET'])
def getvalue():
    hr_num = random.randint(57, 89)
    str_data = json.dumps({"value": hr_num, "time" : date_time})
    return str_data;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', debug=True)
```

Result:

```
{
  "value": 60, 
  "time": "Mon, 02 Sep 2019 22:39:06 GMT"
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting the same error you're getting.  First I got `NameError: name 'random' is not defined` which I fixed by importing `random` then I got `TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable`.  One way to 'fix' this is is by converting the datetime to a str with `str(date_time)`.  After that works for me.

Comment: @CoryNezin Thanks for your response. Yes I did change the date_time to string and imported random. It works for me in http://localhost:5000/properties/value. But my remote server to where i have configured my application, doesn't accept this json structure. I tried with jsonify as well. That's why I want to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: How is the json being sent to the remote server?

Comment: I solved the problem. I gave wrong endpoint in my route. I have a json file which has different href link, because of which the server didn't accept this json data. Thanks for all your help.